# Within what limits Github actions/cache work?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I don't quite understand the extent to which Github **actions/cache** works, what I mean:

Caching works fine if I make a pull request and then in the same pull request I add 1 more commit, but if I create a new pull request in the same branch - the caching is reset and starts again, but why?

Is there any way to extend file caching to all `yml` files and so that each pull request uses existing caching?

Because to speed up the work it turns out - that developers always need to pour their work into one branch, and it somehow sounds like some nonsense.

### Info

My caching key is formed as follows

```
- uses: actions/cache@v2
  id: composer-cache
  with:
     path: .github/docker/development/php-cli/composer/cache
     key: ${{ runner.os }}-develop-composer-${{ hashFiles('src/composer.lock') }}
     restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-develop-composer-
```

Comment: What's your caching key based on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, GitHub's cache action has unintuitive behavior across branches. Pull request workflows don't share, and tag workflows never get a cache hit.

Per [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#restrictions-for-accessing-a-cache) (useful bit made bold):

> A workflow can access and restore a cache created in the current branch, the base branch (including base branches of forked repositories), or the default branch (usually `main`). **For example, a cache created on the default branch would be accessible from any pull request.** Also, if the branch `feature-b` has the base branch `feature-a`, a workflow triggered on `feature-b` would have access to caches created in the default branch (`main`), `feature-a`, and `feature-b`.

So the solution then is to make a separate workflow triggered by pushes to `main` — plus any base branches you like — just to keep a fresh cache available to pull requests and tags.

Comment: Bow. You saved me a lot of time both on the pipeline and on the minutes in github actions, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. I literally just figured it out this weekend and found your question here while looking for the answer myself.

Comment: Thanks for this as it helped me. I had to add another trigger `on: push: branches [ --- ]` for the cache to actually work.

Comment: Wouldn't this job need to run on every runner though? or do GitHub action runners have a mechanism for sharing cache between them?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no mechanism for sharing cache between VMs. I could probably achieve that with rsync. Meanwhile, I was able to pre-populate cache using this hacky approach https://gist.github.com/gajus/67f1ce8cbe95ff46746e8a9fe43a1dbc