# Why can't my cache action triggered inside a pull request not access the cache that exists within the base branch being merged to?

Tags: caching, github-actions, cicd

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that is triggered when a pull request is created to dev. It downloads some pip dependencies and lints the project using PyLint. In this action, it looks for a cache of the pip dependencies. If it is found, it is used to download the requirements. After the pull request is merged, I have a post merge workflow that is triggered. This workflow has an action that will cache the pip dependencies on the branch dev if it doesn't already exist. Therefore, any subsequent pull request to dev workflows should have access to this cache.

I had the same intuition as this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365200/github-actions-how-to-cache-dependencies-between-workflow-runs-of-different-bra) and very closely followed to try and emulate what they had but was unable to produce the same results. Another question I came across was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563672/within-what-limits-github-actions-cache-work) which recommends the same thing as what I'm trying to do below. Initially, I saw that the cache was being installed to the specific pull request i.e. `refs/pull/.../merge` and I understood that this was why no subsequent pull requests had access to the cache. The pull request cache action looks as such:

```
pylint-backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'

      - name: Cache pip packages
        id: cache-pip
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/pip
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pip-

      - name: Checking existence of pip cache
        run: echo "Cache exists ${{ steps.cache-pip.outputs.cache-hit }}"
  
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r ./back-end/requirements.txt
          pip install pylint
```

To get around this, I read through the cache documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563672/within-what-limits-github-actions-cache-work) which said that a feature branch would have access to the caches on the base branch. Therefore, I included a post merge to dev action which would create this cache on the dev branch. This action looks as such:

```
  create-pip-cache:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'

      - name: Creating the cache, won't create if it exists
        id: cache-pip
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/pip
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pip-

      - name: Installing dependencies if the cache doesn't hit
        if: ${{ steps.cache-pip.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        run: pip install -r ./back-end/clientdek/requirements.txt
```

Now, after both workflows have run, as expected, the pull request workflow couldn't find the cache because it did not exist on dev yet. I merged the branch and the post merge action ran. Now, the cache DOES exist on dev. I created another pull request to dev from another branch. The cache action in the pull request workflow looks for the exact same cache with the exact same hash in its key but still says that it was not found. Why is this so ? I've verified that the cache with that exact key exists on dev, so why does a workflow being triggered by a pull request from a child branch of dev unable to find a cache on dev if the documentation says that it can ? My guess is that any push workflow to my child branch will have access to the dev cache but a pull request is running in a different environment and hence, does not have access.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this issue. The problem is that in my post merge workflow, the header looked as such:

```
name: Post Dev Merge Tasks
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - "closed"
    branches: [dev]
```

While this created the cache on the dev branch, it was not accessible to the pull request workflow.
To fix this, I changed it to

```
name: Post Dev Merge Tasks
on:
  push:
    branches: [dev]
  workflow_dispatch:
```

This made all the difference and the pull request workflow was able to access the cache.